# Redis получить все значения hash

Tags: redis

Здраствуйте. Есть данные,сохраненные в Redis структуры типа:[image: структура данных]

Вопрос: как вытащить все данные конкретного `route`? То есть мне нужно вывести `route`(№ роута):все данные по его `track`-ах, неважно какое количество их может быть у одного `route`. Есть ли простой способ или придется делать циклом? Спасибо

Comment: Насколько необходимо хранить треки в виде хеша? Возможно имеет смысл сериализовать их и хранить все треки роута в одном хеше.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать индекс и поддерживать его в актуальном состоянии - для каждого `route` можно создавать `List` или `Set` и добавлять в него ключи `track`.
Т.е. для `route:0`:

```
LPUSH route:0:tracks route:0:track:0
LPUSH route:0:tracks route:0:track:1
```

Для получения всех значений вызываете

```
LRANGE route:0:tracks 0 -1.
```

Если `track` может удаляться или отвязываться от `route` - нужно также  удалять из списка:

```
lrem route:0:tracks route:0:track:1
```

Если вам не важен порядок вставки, можно использовать `Set` - https://redis.io/commands#set.